# How to access `this` from inside .map() array in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Here is a demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/23l3p906zj)

I want to access `this` inside an array. Specifically,

```
this.props.categoryOpen.toString()
```

throws an error when used as follows.

https://codesandbox.io/s/23l3p906z

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.categoryOpen.toString()}
        {this.rows.map(row => (
          <div>
            {row.cells.map(cell => (
              <div key={cell.label}>
                {cell.label}: {cell.data}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  rows = [
    {
      cells: [
        {
          label: "Cell A",
          data: {this.props.categoryOpen.toString()}, // breaks
          //data: "Foo" // works
        },
        {
          label: "Cell B",
          data: "Bar"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}

export default Child;
```

An arrow function also throws an error.

```
rows = () => [...
```

How can I access `this`?

[image: breaking code illustration]

Comment: The problem is not ` this`, the problem is that you have a syntax error. The brackets indicate that you're trying to create an object but there is no key. What is the shape you want for your data?

Comment: Why don't you create a global variable which is declared in the scope of the module and assign it 'this' before going into your map function, then use the global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't statically define your rows like that, or in the constructor, because they won't update when the input props change. In order to have the component re-render automatically when the props change you need to re-generate the rows in the render function.

So just make a method in your component called `getRows` (or something) and call that from `render`. That'll have the side effect of making `this` properly and normally accessible too.

```
class Child extends Component {
  getRows() {
    return [
      {
        cells: [
          {
            label: "Cell A",
            data: this.props.categoryOpen.toString(),
          },
          {
            label: "Cell B",
            data: "Bar"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

  render() {
    const rows = this.getRows()
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.categoryOpen.toString()}
        {rows.map(row => (
          <div>
            {row.cells.map(cell => (
              <div key={cell.label}>
                {cell.label}: {cell.data}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }


}

export default Child;
```

Of course you could just generate `rows` inline in the render method too, but breaking it out into its own method can help with readability.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `{}` around data. It should work

Updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/y0oo2v1xvv

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by other comments you have a syntax error in the `data` field definition.
Also I did not know this but apparently you can make reference to the lexical context (which is the current component instance here) in class field definition. Worth noting they are not part of the language yet and I would advise to use the constructor for this, which is equivalent as per the [Babel transform](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECK0G8BQ1pmgXmgFwBYEsIA6EAexAG4kBfIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=).

`rows` is a field which is defined at construction time, if you want to refer to the current instance you need to use the constructor

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor () {
    this.rows = [
      {
        cells: [
          {
            label: "Cell A",
            data: this.props.categoryOpen.toString(), // breaks
            //data: "Foo" // works
          },
          {
            label: "Cell B",
            data: "Bar"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.categoryOpen.toString()}
        {this.rows.map(row => (
          <div>
            {row.cells.map(cell => (
              <div key={cell.label}>
                {cell.label}: {cell.data}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the curly braces

```
{
    label: "Cell A",
    data: this.props.categoryOpen.toString(), // remove curly braces
    //data: "Foo" // works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap variable with ticks like this.

```
data: `${this.props.categoryOpen.toString()}`,
```

this 
should be fine